# Git not tracking game files with Libgdx

Tags: git, android-studio, libgdx

I am having issues with using Git with Libgdx.

I simply initialized git in the directory which Libgdx generated.

Whenever I try to push something

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   core/src/com/naotoida/mygame (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit
```

It did tell me something about a submodule one time, but I don't use any of those. How can I have Git track `core/src/com/naotoida/mygame`?

I've already tried `git add .` which is supposed to include all.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you executed `git add .` it won't necessarily have matched your file. The easiest way to tell git to add your file is to explicitly execute `git add core/src/com/naotoida/mygame` from the root of the git repository (or simply `git add mygame` if you're in the same directory as `mygame`).

Comment: I've done "git add core/src/com/naotoida/mygame", yet it still gives me the same error.

Comment: What exactly is `mygame`? is it a file? A directory? Looking at the error more closely I'm now guessing that, contrary to your claim, it is actually a submodule. In the root of your project what does it say if you run `git submodule`? And (assuming `mygame` is a directory) what does it say if you `cd` to that directory and run `git status`?

Comment: "mygame" is the directory generated by libgdx by naming my game "mygame". In the root of my project, "git submodule" gives me "No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'core/src/com/naotoida/mygame'".

Comment: That further suggests that `mygame` is a git repository itself (running `git status` in the `mygame` directory would confirm that). If you don't want to treat `mygame` as a module you could delete the `.git` directory, but if you don't know how it was created I can't guarantee it won't be initialized again.